# binary tree for sorting and search on c program

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

So i have a program to data the users input.
in this program i want to make some function

1. to ask the user for the product coming in
2. to display the history of data coming in by sorting by date.
3. to ask the user for the product coming out
4. to display the history of data coming out by sorting by date.
5. to search a specific product data by calling the code
6. to display all the data, the data is sorted by date and then the weight is data coming in minus data coming out

actually i have made a complete program of this, but the teacher updated the assignment. in the previous assignment i mostly use array instead of pointer and for sorting i use recursive bubble sort.

For now i need someone's help to make a sort by date using binary tree and search by product code using binary tree

Note : i must use binary tree because that's the assignment my teacher gave me

assignments are :

1. have a function with address argument
2. have a function with array argument
3. have function with argument as address to a structure
4. have a function with structure argument
5. add node to linked list/stack/queue/tree
6. read/delete node from linked list/stack/queue/tree.

Honestly i still understand linked list/stack/queue/tree. i thought to make a linked list i just change my array to a pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct { 
    int kode;       
    int amount;         
    char variety[20];   
    int weight;         
    int date;   
}data;

data *innData;
data *outtData;

int menu;                       
int i;                      
int pointIn = 0, pointOut=0;    
int amount = 0;                 

char variety[5][20] = {"Fish", "Crab", "Squid", "Clam", "Lobster"}; 

void sortDate(data *list, int range); 
void back_menu();

void input();           
void inputHistory();    
void output();          
void outHistory();  
//void sort
//void calculateWeight
//void search();
//void showAll();


int main(){ 

    innData=(data *)malloc(100*sizeof(data)); 
    outtData=(data *)malloc(100*sizeof(data)); 
    
    do {
        printf(" ---------------- MARINE PRODUCT STOCK PROGRAM ---------------");     
        printf( " \n\nMAIN MENU :\n");
        printf( "___________________________________________________________________\n\n");
        printf( " 1. Input Product\n\n"); //data that the user input
        printf( " 2. Entered History\n\n"); //show the history of the entered data by sorting the date
        printf( " 3. Output Product\n\n"); //data that the user take out
        printf( " 4. Exited Product\n\n");//show the history of the exited data by sorting the date
        printf( " 5. Search Product\n\n"); //show the specific product by calling the code of the product
        printf( " 6. Show All Product\n\n"); 
        printf( " _____________________________\n\n");
        printf( " choose (1 - 6) : "); 
        scanf ("%d", &menu); 

        if (menu < 1 || menu > 2) { 
            system("cls");
            printf ("Please select the number between 1-2\n");
            back_menu();
            }
        switch(menu) { 
            case 1:
                input();
                break;
            case 2:
                inputHistory(); 
                break;
            case 3:
                output();
                break;
            case 4:
                outHistory(); 
                break;
//          case 5:
//                  search(); // this function is used to search specific product by entering the code
//              break;
//          case 6:
//                  showAll(); // this function is used to show all of the stock in the warehouse. but the weight = input-output
//              break;

            }
free(innData);
free(outtData);

    }
    
    while (menu != 6);
    system("cls");
    printf ("============ Thankyou for using our program ============");

    return 0;
}


void input(){ 
    int code; 
        
            system ("cls");
            printf("================= INPUT MENU =================\n\n");
            printf("Enter the number of items to be recorded : "); scanf("%d", &amount); 
            printf( "_________________________________________________________________\n");
            
            printf("\n Kode 0 = Fish \n kode 1 = Crab \n kode 2 = Squid \n kode 3 = Clam \n kode 4 = Lobster\n\t\t\t   "); 
        
            for(i = 0; i < amount; i++){ 
                printf("\n\nPRODUCT ORDER-%d",pointIn + 1);
                printf("\n\tInput code\t : "); scanf(" %d", &code);
                
                if(code < 0 || code > 4){ 
                    printf ("product with that number is not available, select number 0-4\n");
                    i--;
                }
                else {
                    strcpy( (innData+pointIn)->variety, variety[code]); 
                    (innData+pointIn)->kode = code;  
                
                    printf("\tvariety\t\t : %s\n", (innData+pointIn)->variety);
                    printf("\t Weight\t : "); scanf(" %d", &(innData+pointIn)->weight );
                    printf("\t Date (YYYYMMDD)\t : ");scanf(" %d", &(innData+pointIn)->date); 
                    pointIn++;
                    }
                }
        back_menu(); 
    
}

void inputHistory(){ 
    system("cls");
    
    printf("*****  INPUT STOCK DATE HISTORY ***** \n" );
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("|  DATE  |  CODE  |      NAME      |  WEIGHT | \n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    
    //call sort function here
    
    for (i = 0; i < pointIn; i++){ 
        printf("   %d      %d          %s         %d            \n", (innData+i)->date,(innData+i)->kode, (innData+i)->variety,(innData+i)->weight) ;   
    }
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    
    back_menu();
}

void output(){ 
    int code; 
        
            system ("cls");
            printf("================= INPUT MENU =================\n\n");
            printf("Enter the number of items to be recorded : "); scanf("%d", &amount); 
            printf( "_________________________________________________________________\n");
            
            printf("\n Kode 0 = Fish \n kode 1 = Crab \n kode 2 = Squid \n kode 3 = Clam \n kode 4 = Lobster\n\t\t\t   "); 
        
            for(i = 0; i < amount; i++){ 
                printf("\n\nPRODUCT ORDER-%d",pointOut + 1);
                printf("\n\tInput code\t : "); scanf(" %d", &code);
                
                if(code < 0 || code > 4){ 
                    printf ("product with that number is not available, select number 0-4\n");
                    i--;
                }
                else {
                    strcpy( (outtData+pointOut)->variety, variety[code]); 
                    (outtData+pointOut)->kode = code;  
                
                    printf("\tvariety\t\t : %s\n", (outtData+pointOut)->variety);
                    printf("\tWeight\t : "); scanf(" %d", &(outtData+pointOut)->weight );
                    printf("\tDate (YYYYMMDD)\t : ");scanf(" %d", &(outtData+pointOut)->date); 
                    pointOut++;
                    }
                }
        back_menu(); 
    
}

void outHistory(){ 
    system("cls");
    
    printf("*****  EXIT STOCK DATE HISTORY ***** \n" );
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("|  DATE  |  CODE  |      NAME      |  WEIGHT | \n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    
    //call sort function here
    
    for (i = 0; i < pointIn; i++){ 
        printf("   %d      %d          %s         %d            \n", (outtData+i)->date,(outtData+i)->kode, (outtData+i)->variety,(outtData+i)->weight) ;   
    }
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    
    back_menu();
}

void back_menu(){ 
    printf("\n\n\t\t\tPress any key to continue.....");
    getch();
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but note that e.g. `(innData+pointIn)->variety` is *exactly* equal to `innData[pointIn].variety`. The latter is easier to read and understand (and less to write). Please use the array-indexing syntax instead. Also, if you always allocate `100` elements, why don't you define an *array* instead, as in `data innData[100];`?

Comment: As for your problem, why do you need a tree to sort and search the data? What is your actual assignment or exercise? Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the full and complete assignment text into the question, including all requirements and limitations.

Comment: actually i have made a complete program of this, but the teacher updated the assignment. in the previous assignment i mostly use array instead of pointer and for sorting i use recursive bubble sort. 
but the new assignments are :
1. have a function with address argument
2. have a function with array argument
3. have function with argument as address to a structure
4. have a function with structure argument
5. add node to linked list/stack/queue/tree
6. read/delete node from linked list/stack/queue/tree.

honestly i still don't understand about linked list/stack/queue/tree.

Comment: i thought, to make a linked list i just change the array from my previous program to a pointer....

Comment: As an addendum to @Someprogrammerdude's first suggestion, unless you need a really big array, dynamically allocating an array in `main` is likely a sign that something's gone wrong. If you are going to do that, make sure you `free` that memory.